# how to do incremental construction of the minimal model in logic programming?

Tags: programming-languages, logic, first-order-logic

I was reading a book titled "Essentials of Logic Programming.", most parts of the book are easy to understand. but now having a problem with Theme 45: incremental constructions of the minimal model. The relevant parts are shown below.

Some notations: $P$ is a definite program, $B(P)$ is the Herbrand base of $P$, $G(P)$ is a ground instantiation of $P$, $MM(P)$ is a minimal model of $P$.

Theme 45 explains the incremental constructions of the minimal model as follows.

> The method starts by choosing some interpretation $I_1 \subseteq B(P)$. Later on, we shall see that there is a preferred choice of $I_1$ and that not all choices are adequate. Choosing $I_1$ can be viewed as guessing which atoms have to be true in any model of $P$. Now consider any clause in $G(P)$
> kind(Chris)
> q if body

> if our guess assigns true to all atoms in this body then an immediate consequence of that guess is that q should also be made true, for otherwise the clause as a whole would be made false. Our next iterate $I_2$ comprise just those heading atoms q made true by this argument. This new iterate will not necessarily contain all those body atoms which justified the introduction of the new atoms q; this does not matter - successive iterates will eventually introduce and retain all of these atoms which must be true in any model of the program. Consider this example of a program $P$ on the domain $H=\{ dov,chris\}$:

> kind(X) if nice (X)

> nice(X)

> whose ground instantiation $G(P$ is highly abbreviated form is

> kind(dov) if nice(dov)

> kind(Chris) if nice(Chris)

> nice(dov)

> (where K=kind, N=nice, D=dov,C=Chris)

> and suppose we choose $I_1= \{ kind(dov),nice(Chris)\}$.
> Applying the above method yields $I_2= \{ nice(dov), kind(Chris)\}$ and $I_3= \{ nice(dov), kind(dov)\}$
> All further iterates merely replicates $I_3$, which is accordingly referred to as a fixpoint. We have, in fact, converged upon the minimal model $MM(P)$.

Let me explain how I understand or did not understand this example.

1. is $I_1$ a guess? why not just make $I_1 = \{ nice(Chris)\}$?
2. nice(Chris) leads to kind(Chris) is true, so "kind(Chris) if nice(Chris)" is true. So, we have kind(Chris) in $I_2$. But why there is nice(dov) in $I_2$?
3. as said further iterates will replicate $I_3$, but I did not see how this works because I did not see the iterate from $I_1$ to $I_2$.

I just did not get this example. Could anyone clarify it to me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please expand all the abbreviations.

Comment: @ShyPerson abbreviations are given:  where K=kind, N=nice, D=dov, C=Chris.  This is exactly what is written in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this paragraph describes the immediate consequences operator $T_P(I) = \{ a \mid \text{there exists a rule } r \in G(P) \text{ with } head(r)=a \text{ and } body(r) \subseteq I \}$ for some interpretation $I$ modelled as a set of ground terms.

What is the significance of this operator ? We start from an interpretation and try to find a model. Now it might be the case that there are rules where the body is true, but the head is not yet true. In order to create a model we have to add the new head to the interpretation which is done by $T_P$. Since we are especially interested in the least model, we also don't want unnecessary items, i.e. elements for which is no rule with a true body. This is the second effect of this operator.

Now we look at the example. They start with $I_1 = \{ kind(dov),nice(Chris)\}$ and we will check every rule from $G(P)$ to compute $I_2 = T_P(I_1)$

1. kind(dov) if nice(dov): nice(dov) is not in $I_1$, so we don't need kind(dov) in $I_2 = \emptyset$
2. kind(Chris) if nice(Chris): nice(Chris) is inside $I_1$ we need kind(Chris) in $I_2 = \{ kind(Chris)\}$
3. nice(dov): This rule has no body so is always true. So we also need this in the body. Now $I_2 = \{kind(Chris), nice(dov) \}$

Now we repeat this process with $I_2$ and compute $I_3 = T_P(I_2)$. At the start $I_3 = \emptyset$ as previously.

1. kind(dov) if nice(dov): Now nice(dov) is in $I_2$, so $I_3 = \{kind(dov) \}$
2. kind(Chris) if nice(Chris): nice(Chris) is not in $I_2$ so $I_3$ stays the same.
3. nice(dov): is the same as previously

So $I_3 = \{ kind(dov), nice(dov) \}$. Try it with this again and you will notice that $I_4 = T_P(I_3)$ equals $I_3$ is a fixed-point of $T_P$. This is significant as we can now stop our computation.

Now is this dependent on the program and we were lucky ? If you analyse the operator $T_P$ on interpretations, you will notice that it is monotonouos and by the [Knaster-Tarski-fixed-point-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem) exists always a least fixed point. This can be proven to be the same as the minimal model of a definite logic program.

The interpretation $I_1$ was choosen arbitrarly. Does it matter which interpretation we start with ? Consider the following logic program $P_2$ (which is already grounded):

$ p \leftarrow q \\ q \leftarrow p $

You will notice that it has two fixed-points $\emptyset$ and $\{ p,q\}$. Each of them is a model, but $\emptyset$ is the least model. This is the result by starting with $\emptyset$. In fact, the [Kleene-fixed-point-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_fixed-point_theorem) tells us that starting with the minimum element is the way to calculate the least fixed-point (if some conditions hold).

If you would start however with $\{p\}$ you would alternate between $\{p\}$ and $\{q\}$ and would never reach a fixed-point, so the choice matters.

Comment: Now I realize that I missed that "nice(dov)" is always true, because it is just a fact (correct me if I am mistaken). The second example is a very nice one. It is clear now, Thank you!